# Is auto installation through preseed files still present in ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: system-installation, 20.04, preseed

Is auto installation through preseed files still present in Ubuntu 20.04 ?

Comment: Why not? Have you tried using it?

Comment: Yes ! I'm trying to, but that's not a win atm : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238696/preseed-autoinstall-does-not-work-on-20-04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. If you are asking about the desktop.

Only the server version started using a new method (18.04 got a new installer for the server version and we lost preseeding back then). The desktop, I hope, will follow this new method as it would make it 100% compatible with our installer. [More on this][1].

Comment: Yes i was talking about desktop :)

Comment: Got this using url preseed : https://imgur.com/AbIE2JJ

grub.cfg
```
menuentry "Auto Install Ubuntu Server From Preseed" {
  set gfxpayload=keep
  linux /casper/vmlinuz boot=casper url=http://192.168.100.111/imt.seed auto=true priority=critical locale=fr_FR  quiet ---
  initrd  /casper/initrd
}
```
And isolinux/txt.cfg
```
label  auto-install
  menu label ^Auto Install Ubuntu Server From Preseed
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz
  append  boot=casper auto url=http://192.168.100.111/imt.seed vga=788 initrd=/casper/initrd auto=true priority=critical locale=fr_FR  quiet ---
```

Comment: Looks good. The errors look like those are related to it being an installer and not an installed system(?)

Comment: Don't know what that's mean ;D