# Preseed autoinstall does not work on 20.04

Tags: grub2, system-installation, 20.04, preseed

Trying to autoinstall a desktop using a preseed file.

Got this for an anwser :

```
root@ubuntu:/var/log# cat casper.log 
Begin: Running /scripts/casper-premount ... done.
done.
mount: mounting /cow on /root/cow failed: No such file or directory
done.
Begin: Creating debconf-communicate fifo mechanism ... done.
Begin: Running /scripts/casper-bottom ... Connecting to plymouth: Connection refused
Begin: Moving mount points... ... done.
Begin: Configuring fstab... ... done.
Begin: Setting up swap... ... done.
Begin: Setting up locales... ... Generating locales (this might take a while)...
Generation complete.
done.
Begin: Setting up automatic login... ... done.
Begin: Disabling systemd's GPT auto generator... ... done.
Begin: Setting hostname... ... done.
Begin: Setting up console keyboard... ... done.
Begin: Applying desktop settings... ... done.
Begin: Regenerating SSL certificate... ... done.
Begin: Loading preseed file... ... done.
Begin: Adding live session user... ... passwd: password expiry information changed.
dbus-daemon[2458]: [session uid=999 pid=2458] Activating service name='org.gtk.vfs.Daemon' requested by ':1.0' (uid=999 pid=2459 comm="" label="unconfined")
dbus-daemon[2458]: [session uid=999 pid=2458] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.Daemon'
dbus-daemon[2458]: [session uid=999 pid=2458] Activating service name='org.gtk.vfs.Metadata' requested by ':1.0' (uid=999 pid=2459 comm="" label="unconfined")
fuse: device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first
dbus-daemon[2458]: [session uid=999 pid=2458] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.Metadata'
A connection to the bus can't be made
done.
Begin: Setting up init... ... done.
Begin: Configuring accessibility options... ... done.
Begin: Disabling update-notifier... ... done.
Begin: Configuring power management... ... done.
Begin: Enabling detection of crashes... ... done.
Begin: Disabling unnecessary KDE services... ... done.
Begin: Fixing language selector... ... done.
Begin: Disabling trackerd... ... done.
Begin: Adding APT-CDROM source... ... Using CD-ROM mount point /cdrom/
Identifying... [b0f8b03c0b3a665e1f04d8fe925b7e90-2]
Scanning disc for index files...
Found 2 package indexes, 0 source indexes, 0 translation indexes and 1 signatures
Found label 'Ubuntu 20.04.0 2020.05.12 LTS amd64 _Custom Focal Fossa_ (20200512)'
This disc is called: 
'Ubuntu 20.04.0 2020.05.12 LTS amd64 _Custom Focal Fossa_ (20200512)'
Copying package lists...gpgv: Signature made Thu Apr 23 07:51:19 2020 UTC
gpgv:                using RSA key D94AA3F0EFE21092
gpgv: Good signature from "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) <cdimage@ubuntu.com>"
Reading Package Indexes... Done
Writing new source list
Source list entries for this disc are:
deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 20.04.0 2020.05.12 LTS amd64 _Custom Focal Fossa_ (20200512)]/ focal main restricted
Repeat this process for the rest of the CDs in your set.
done.
Begin: Possibly disabling update-initramfs (useless on a live CD)... ... done.
Begin: Grant administrative PolicyKit privileges to default user... ... done.
Begin: Configuring jackd2... ... done.
Begin: Disabling unity8's first run wizard... ... done.
Begin: Disabling gnome-initial-setup... ... done.
Begin: Disabling security unattended-upgrades... ... done.
Begin: Disabling snap refresh... ... done.
Begin: Overriding 71-nvidia.rules... ... done.
Begin: Configuring pollinate... ... done.
```

And booting to live without auto install.
I've tried to modify grub & isolinux, currently :
grub.cfg :

```
menuentry "IMT" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz boot=casper file=/cdrom/preseed/imt.seed auto=true priority=critical locale=fr_FR quiet ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd
}
```

isolinux/txt.cfg :

```
default imt
label imt
  menu label ^IMY
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz
  append  boot=casper file=/cdrom/preseed/imt.seed vga=788 initrd=/casper/initrd auto=true priority=critical locale=fr_FR quiet ---
```

and the .seed file

```
### Automatic Installation
d-i auto-install/enable boolean true
d-i debconf/priority select critical

### Localization
d-i debian-installer/locale string fr_FR
d-i localechooser/supported-locales multiselect en_US.UTF-8, fr_FR.UTF-8
# Keyboard
d-i console-setup/ask_detect boolean false
d-i keyboard-configuration/xkb-keymap select fr

### Network
d-i netcfg/choose_interface select auto
d-i netcfg/link_wait_timeout string 10
d-i netcfg/dhcp_timeout string 30
d-i netcfg/get_hostname string imt-test
d-i netcfg/get_domain string imt
#d-i netcfg/hostname string $hostname
#d-i netcfg/domain string $domaine
d-i hw-detect/load_firmware boolean true

### Apt
d-i mirror/http/mirror select fr.archive.ubuntu.com

### Account
d-i passwd/root-login boolean true
d-i passwd/root-password-crypted password $6$Tlc9BpTSuN0WUJC7$UcrBQBEKfP99ExtCU4WA5pXryCnU0veQpduz9XVgaYiVtjs1C9K.nrbgxFBG3zGa2Ihie41GbswPehLsoDw4v/
# User
d-i passwd/user-fullname string imt
d-i passwd/user-password-crypted $6$ZRTZsEZm6Z9Y3Jfq$sGXB4Ao3EPLwLR8jJ3U4CQZNmygYyVmPP45m/id3.W45EbNfFISsRwoTTGtPIBySoCjFGiX7jtfdvW/Lz4yT1/
d-i user-setup/allow-password-weak boolean true

### Time
d-i clock-setup/utc-auto boolean true
d-i clock-setup/ntp boolean true
d-i clock-setup/ntp-server string ntp.laas.fr

### Disk
d-i partman-auto/method string crytpo
d-i partman-crypto/passphrase toto
d-i partman-crypto/passphrase-again toto
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
d-i partman-auto-lvm/guided_size string max
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select atomic
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true

# Base system installation (voir B.4.9)
# Apt
## Repo
d-i apt-setup/restricted boolean true
d-i apt-setup/universe boolean true
d-i apt-setup/multiverse boolean true
d-i apt-setup/backports boolean true
d-i apt-setup/services-select multiselect security
d-i apt-setup/security_host string security.ubuntu.com
d-i apt-setup/security_path string /ubuntu

tasksel tasksel/first multiselect ubuntu-desktop
d-i pkgsel/include string openssh-server build-essential vim
## Whether to upgrade packages after debootstrap.
#d-i pkgsel/upgrade select safe-upgrade
d-i pkgsel/language-packs multiselect fr, en
d-i pkgsel/update-policy select unattended-upgrades

d-i pkgsel/updatedb boolean true

d-i grub-installer/only_debian boolean true
d-i grub-installer/with_other_os boolean true
d-i grub-installer/bootdev  string default

d-i finish-install/reboot_in_progress note
```

using cubic on ubuntu 20.04 update to generate the iso

Need help =)

Comment: Is someone here ? :D

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a preseed file for Ubuntu server operating systems and installing a desktop os set of packages through it.
It is noticeable due to stanzas such as:

```
### Apt
d-i mirror/http/mirror select fr.archive.ubuntu.com
# Base system installation (voir B.4.9)
# Apt
## Repo
```

Preseeding is a method of answering installation question prompts for the user, allowing them to auto configure their install.

Ubuntu server and Ubuntu desktop use different methods of system installation, resulting different types of preseeding.

Although Ubuntu desktop does support preseeding, it is much thinner when it comes to what you can preseed, and supports much less options than an Ubuntu server install. Thus, resulting many parameters and commands you entered here as irrelevant and not read by the installer.
That is why people try to trick the server installer to install a desktop set of packages.  **In the past, using this method used to work**, but from my understanding it is not supported in version 20.04.

I haven't tried preseeding an Ubuntu 20.04 install to test for new feature yet, but I am very sure this is not the correct format.

In addition, this thread and its references also might provide you with more information: [How to preseed ubuntu 20.04 desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233454/how-to-preseed-ubuntu-20-04-desktop)